# how many elements of order 2 are in symmetric group 6?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to find all elements of order 2 in $S_6$ symmetric group $6$. I am trying to understand how to achieve this. the solution says:

$6C_2+6C_4\cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot 4C_2+6C_2\cdot 4C_2\cdot \frac{1}{3}= 75$. I get the $6C_2$ bit but not the other bits. can someone please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An element has order 2 in $S_6$ if and only if it is a product of disjoint transpositions.
Thus all we have to do is count the number of transpositions, the number of products of two disjoint transpositions, and the number of products of 3 disjoint transpositions (this is the same as counting the number of elements in each of the conjugacy classes (-,-) , (-,-)(-,-) and (-,-)(-,-)(-,-)).

To count these we use that (a,b) = (b,a).

To count the transpositions just count how many ways you can choose 2 elements from 6:
${6\choose2} = 15$

The products of two transpositions is just the number of ways of choosing 4 elements from 6, and then times the number of ways of distributing those 4 elements into the two transpositions:
${6\choose4}{4\choose2}\frac{1}{2!} = 45$

To count the number of products of three transpositions just count the number of ways you can distribute all of the 6 elements into the 3 distinct transpositions:
${6\choose2}{4\choose2}\frac{1}{3!} = 15$

Add them up and you get 75.

Answer (score 0):

An element of order 2 must have the form $(ab)$, or $(ab)(cd)$ or $(ab)(cd)(ef)$, where the transpositions are disjoint.

There are 15,45,15 of each type. Total 75.

That is not hard to see: for the first type there are ${6\choose2}$. For the second type there are $\frac{1}{2}{6\choose2}{4\choose2}$ - ie ${6\choose2}$ ways of choosing a pair, then ${4\choose2}$ ways of choosing a second pair, but that counts every possibility twice. For the third type there are 5 choices to pair with 1, then three ways of pairing the remaining four.